# VSC returns errors with an <a href='file../> reference in Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Pretty much the title, for some reason VSC started to reference my errors when executing Python scripts with `<a href='file../>` which makes it really difficult to figure out what is going on and where the error is.

Have anyone experienced this and if so, how would I fix it?

Example:

```py
<a href='file://c:\Users\SomeUser\SomePath\test.py?line=17'>18</a> print(1/0)
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Picture:
[image]

It appeared when running the simple script of

```py
print(1/0)
```

Additional note is that if I import a module and an error is raised there, then I the error comes out in a standard format and not with the <a href

Comment: What kind of script did this appear when you were running? It will be better solved if you can provide us with more information, such as the steps and code to reproduce the problem in a minimal way, the environment you use, etc.

Comment: Added it, but you can see it in the error, its simply just print(1/0), there is nothing else to it, and just a standard Anaconda Python in VSC

Comment: -When the denominator is zero, the console will display "ZeroDivisionError: division by zero". Could you provide relevant screenshots so that we can check more relevant factors?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/IcUwl7B see here, the problem is not the error it throws but that it puts <a href infront of it which bloats my output and makes it difficult to see what is going wrong.

Comment: @nonein are you using any plugins? Looks like an issue with plugin, may be?

Comment: Can you share .py file with MVP, it seems to be working fine.

Comment: No plugins and a .py file would literally just be:
print(1/0)

Comment: It looks like to do with the `Terminal Link` API, have you updated the extensions, latest ms-Python is `v2020.9.114305`, Are you using `PyLance` the new Language Server for Python. I use `Pylance` and are happy with it. Where do you see this error?

Comment: Hmm I have not updated anything explicit, I get this error when running code with an error, I use the Python Interactive window, it only shows the href when referring to my own file, for files that are imported the errors shown are normal if that provides any indication of where the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This went away with the latest update, as such I would think it does not exist anymore as a problem.